# How to hardcode the hex decimal value in transformer?

Tags: datastage

I have a requirement where I need to hardcode the hex-decimal value x'FF' in datastage transformer where the column length is "1". Could any help me how to achieve this ?

Thanks,
Siva

Answer (score 0):

The Char() function returns the character whose ASCII value is the argument.  Therefore:    `Char(255)`

Comment: HI Ray,

when i tried the char(255) in transformer the output has no data like its just space(1) 
but my requirement is insted of blank i need to populate 'FF'. Could you help me how to get that, i tried the NLS option to default and ISO 8859-1  still it give space only, Kindly help me.

Comment: 0xFF is not a displayable character.